# Nginx to serve remote disk

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Is it possible to serve static files with nginx from a remote shared disk?

I am trying to configure nginx in ubuntu to serve video files from a samba shared disk, but i cannot find the way to do it.

In a nutshell, this works:

```
location /videos/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /Volumes/VIDEO_VOL/videos/;
}
```

But this does not:

```
location /videos/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias smb://192.133.2.40/videos_service/;
}
```

Which would be the proper way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: mount your samba drive into your filesystem and your first way of doing this will work: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 0):

Before you need mount the remote dir to host where installed nginx. And then use required path to the video.

Answer (score 0):

One last comment is that the disk must be mounted with cifs

```
sudo mount –t cifs –o username=USER //192.133.2.40/videos_service/ /mnt/videos/
```

If the disk is mounted with gvfs, as it was my case intially it is not found by nginx